# Android database: insert query error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am developing an application requiring persistence functionality.From my limited understanding two classes are required for this - SQLiteHelper class & DatabaseManager class.

To get things moving, I have a simple process that will take a single text input and insert it into the database. However, I am receiving an error:

> 12-29 19:17:47.952: E/SQLiteDatabase(5840): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: UserTable (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO UserTable(username) VALUES (?)

Implying there is no user table, although when onCreate() is called, this table should be created.

I would be really greatful for any assistance in helping to overcome this obstacle. Below are the two classes used in creating the database functionality. Many thanks.

> public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
>
> ```
> private static final String DATABASE_NAME         = "NutrtionIntuition";
> private static final int  DATABASE_VERSION    = 2;
>
> // Database creation sql statement
> private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =   "create table UserTable " +
>                                                 "( _id integer primary key,name text not null);";
>
> public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
>             super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
> }
>
> // Method is called during creation of the database. Method is also called on upgrade of database?
> @Override
> public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
>             database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
> }
>
> // Method is called during an upgrade of the database,
> @Override
> public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
>
>                 database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User");
>                 onCreate(database);
> } }
> ```

```
public class DatabaseManager{  

    private DatabaseHelper      dbHelper;  
    private SQLiteDatabase      database;  

    private static final String     USER_TABLE          = "UserTable";

    public static final String      KEY_ROWID           = "_id";
    public static final String      KEY_USERNAME        = "username";


    public DatabaseManager(Context context){  
      dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);  
      database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();  
    }

    //Insert Records into the User Table
    public long insertRecords(int id, String name){  
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
        //values.put(KEY_ROWID , id);  
        values.put(KEY_USERNAME, name); 
        Log.v("Test","Inserting.....");

        return database.insert(USER_TABLE, null, values);  
    }   

    public Cursor selectRecords() {
         String[] cols = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME};  
         Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, USER_TABLE,cols,null  
              , null, null, null, null, null);  
         if (mCursor != null) {  
          mCursor.moveToFirst();  
       }  
       return mCursor; // iterate to get each value.
    }
}
```

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall your app so any possible old database versions are removed. Or clear your app data to achieve the same.

Comment: ... after which your updated `onCreate()` should run and your app will fail on other issues. Another bug, another logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a table with `_id` and `name`, while inserting you are using  `_id` and `username`.  One more - in `onUpgrade`, `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User` should be `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS UserTable`